# Error installing nokogiri 1.6.0 on mac (libxml2)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, libxml2

**UPDATE: Fixed**

I found the answer in another thread. The workaround I used is to tell Nokogiri to use the system libraries instead:

```
NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 bundle install
```

====

Trying to install nokogiri 1.6.0 on a mac. With previous versions, I had no problems. But 1.6.0 refuses to install. This is the error:

```
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/josenriq/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/i686-apple-darwin11/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... ERROR
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Archive contains obsolescent base-64 headers
tar: Read 3 bytes from /Users/josenriq/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@wdi/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/archives/libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/josenriq/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ruby
/Users/josenriq/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mini_portile-0.5.1/lib/mini_portile.rb:234:in `extract_file': Failed to complete extract task (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/josenriq/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mini_portile-0.5.1/lib/mini_portile.rb:34:in `block in extract'
    from /Users/josenriq/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mini_portile-0.5.1/lib/mini_portile.rb:32:in `each'
    from /Users/josenriq/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mini_portile-0.5.1/lib/mini_portile.rb:32:in `extract'
    from /Users/josenriq/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mini_portile-0.5.1/lib/mini_portile.rb:98:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:101:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:119:in `call'
    from extconf.rb:119:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:109:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:109:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/josenriq/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@wdi/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/josenriq/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@wdi/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Seems like it has something to do with the libxml2 tar file not being able to extract.

Any ideas? I've done maybe 8 hours of research to no avail. Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found the answer in another thread. The workaround I used is to tell Nokogiri to use the system libraries instead:

```
NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 bundle install
```

Comment: Was able to upgrade to nokogiri 1.6.1 on osx 10.6.8 ruby2.1.0 using this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create file build_nokogiri (or whatever) and fill in with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Version
  attr_reader :major, :minor, :patch, :base
  def initialize( str )
    @base = str
    base = File.basename str
    @major, @minor, @patch = base.split('.').map &:to_i
  end

  def <=>(other)
    return -1 if major < other.major
    return 1 if major > other.mahor
    return -1 if minor < other.minor
    return 1 if minor > other.minor
    return -1 if patch < other.patch
    return 1 if patch > other.patch
    0
  end

  def to_s
    "##{self.class.name}{#@major #@minor #@patch  #@base}"
  end
  alias inspect to_s
  alias dir base

  def version
    [major,minor,patch].compact.join('.')
  end
end

class Lookup < Version
  class << self
    attr_accessor :prefix
  end
  def self.find
    Dir[ "/usr/local/Cellar/#{ full_name }/*" ].map { |c| new c }.sort.first
  end

  def self.full_name
    [prefix, name.downcase].compact.join('')
  end

  %w{ include lib }.each { |m| define_method("#{m}_path") { "#{ base }/#{ m }" } }

  def args
    %w{ include lib }.map do |c|
      "--with-#{ self.class.name.downcase }-#{c}=#{ send("#{ c }_path") }"
    end.join(' ')
  end
end

class XML2 < Lookup
  self.prefix = 'lib'
  def include_path
    "#{super}/#{ self.class.full_name }"
  end
end

class XSLT < Lookup
  self.prefix = 'lib'
  def args
    "--with-xslt-dir=#{ dir }"
  end
end

class Iconv < Lookup
  self.prefix = 'lib'
end

puts "Found:"
a = [ XML2.find, XSLT.find, Iconv.find ]

puts a

s="  gem install nokogiri -- #{ a.map(&:args).join(' ') } --use-system-libraries"
puts s

exec s
```

Give this file permission to execute.

Execute file.

This will automatically resolve dependencies installed using brew.