# failed to install gems ruby on rails in rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubymine

I've downloaded and installed RubyMine. I'm trying to update gems, like it said in the [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/quickstart/). Some updated successfully but the nokogirl (1.6.5) gem gives this mistake. Any solutions? I have Mac OS X Yosemite if this is important.
[image]

**UPDATE:** Also these gems failed: actionmailer, actionpack, actionview, jquery-rail, rails, railties, responders.
**UPDATE1**I tried to install it from terminal:

```
sudo gem install rails
nokogiri gem installed, but next were some mistakes.
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.5.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Comment: Is it possible to copy-and-paste the actual text from the error message here rather than using a screenshot? Does this same error occur trying to install the gems via a command line?

Comment: Well, the error is: `The file /usr/include/iconv.h is missing in your build environment, which means you haven't installed XCode commandline tools properly` ... It then follows with instructions on how to install this. So I suggest that you follow those ;-)

Comment: I didn't find where I can get log of mistake and can't copy it from that window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't Nokogiri installing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914169/why-isnt-nokogiri-installing)