# Nokogiri does not install?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, osx-mountain-lion, libxml2

I can't seem to get Nokogiri installed on my Mac OS X 10.8 system.  I know there is a workaround to this solution and the work around is:

```
NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 bundle install
```

But I would rather solve it because every time I do a bundle, it fails.  Here is the problem:

```
$ gem install nokogiri

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/buf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... ERROR, review 'tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/ports/libxml2/2.8.0/configure.log' to see what happened.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog
  --srcdir=.
  --curdir
  --ruby=/Users/buf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby
/Users/buf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@rentify193/gems/mini_portile-0.5.1/lib/mini_portile.rb:251:in `block in execute': Failed to complete configure task (RuntimeError)
  from /Users/buf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@rentify193/gems/mini_portile-0.5.1/lib/mini_portile.rb:243:in `chdir'
  from /Users/buf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@rentify193/gems/mini_portile-0.5.1/lib/mini_portile.rb:243:in `execute'
  from /Users/buf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@rentify193/gems/mini_portile-0.5.1/lib/mini_portile.rb:57:in `configure'
  from /Users/buf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@rentify193/gems/mini_portile-0.5.1/lib/mini_portile.rb:100:in `cook'
  from extconf.rb:101:in `block in <main>'
  from extconf.rb:119:in `call'
  from extconf.rb:119:in `block in <main>'
  from extconf.rb:109:in `tap'
  from extconf.rb:109:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/buf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@rentify193/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/buf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@rentify193/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

And when I look at the log file:

```
configure: error: cannot find sources (entities.c) in /Volumes/Terra/Code/vimsource/vim/src or ..
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: You know some smart person invented error message and we must learn to respect them and start reading them

Comment: This is the error log: configure: error: cannot find sources (entities.c) in /Volumes/Terra/Code/vimsource/vim/src or ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error installing nokogiri 1.6.0 on mac (libxml2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863477/error-installing-nokogiri-1-6-0-on-mac-libxml2)

Answer (score 5):

In Mavericks, using Homebrew to install the libraries the gem depends on first and then setting `NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1` before actually installing the gem did the trick for me.

Summarising:

- If previously installed, uninstall the gem:
  `$ gem uninstall nokogiri`
- Use Homebrew to install `libxml2`, `libxslt` and `libiconv`:
  `$ brew install libxml2 libxslt libiconv`
- Install the gem specifying the paths to the libraries to be linked against:
  `$ NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries --with-iconv-dir="$(brew --prefix libiconv)" --with-xml2-config="$(brew --prefix libxml2)/bin/xml2-config" --with-xslt-config="$(brew --prefix libxslt)/bin/xslt-config"`

After the gem is installed `bundle install`should finish without errors.

Comment: I tried `$ NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 bundle install` instead of installing the gem on its own and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that libxml2-2.8.0 is not getting installed properly. First try installing it and then install Nokogiri.

Comment: I did brew install libxml2 and brew link libxml2 already. No effect.